Firebase Google Oauth (Sign in with google) stuck at loading and ends with timeout for some users (Web - React js)
We are using Google sign in for authentication in our React js application.
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

For most of users, it works fine. but one of our user from Venezuela reported that it the popup is not loading for them.
It opens popup, then stuck at loading state for long time and then ends up with timeout message.
And when they close popup, it gives popup closed error. so we don't have right error message to know what was the reason it wasn't loading for them.
What can be the reason of it?
Popup loading screenshot
Timeout screenshot
We tested it on 2 browsers (Google chrome and Firefox). Same behavior on both platforms. Also network connection is also not the issue here. User had good internet connection.
